# keeping calls to a particular function on the same line

Tags: prettier

I am currently designing a TypeScript API. The usage looks like this:

```
this.selectLastPatient()
    .visitSE_BASELINE()
    .visitFD_DISEASECHARINCL1()
    .selectYes_ID_TU_RELAPYN()
    .enterID_TU_RELAPTUDAT("uu.uu.2022").inRow(0)
    .clickSave()
```

The line of interest here is the one ending with `.inRow(0)`.

Is there any way to tell prettier that calls to a specific function (here: `inRow`) must not be split onto the next line? I want to specify it on the API side, not on the calling side. So `// prettier-ignore` does not help here.

The reason why the row index is not a second parameter of `enterID_TU_RELAPTUDAT` is that the API is meant to be used by non-programmers. So I am trying to make it as simple as possible..

Edit: I created [a feature request](https://github.com/prettier/prettier/issues/14877) called `// prettier-glue-calls`.

Comment: I believe you'd need to develop your own [custom plugin](https://prettier.io/docs/en/plugins.html) for this